# On Linux, for a scsi device, how to make an inquiry call (sg_ll_inquiry()) to page code 00 and check which other pages are supported?

Tags: c, linux, scsi

I want to understand if there is a way to make an inquiry call to page code 00 and retrieve the supported page codes to further make inquiry calls to those page codes. I'm new to scsi and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I want to know if there is a way to retrieve that information from page code 00. I tried looking at the scsi spec but I could not see how to do it. I'm new to scsi and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you happen to be running an operating system of some kind?

Comment: @stark yes, I am using Linux

Comment: On Linux you can use the generic sg driver to send arbitrary SCSI commands.  That's what `sq_inq` uses. https://linux.die.net/man/8/sg_inq

Comment: See also https://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/theory.html